# How to prove $(xyz)^{1/3} \le (x+y+z)/3$ using linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

To elaborate on the title, you can prove that $$\sqrt{xy}\le \frac{x+y}{2}$$ in the following way:

[image: The proof using dot product and Cauchy-Schwarz inequality]

Is there a way that this can be extended to the inequality in the title and to a general case? For example for cube root? I tried the same thing done in the picture with three vectors but only got $$(xyz)^{{1\over 3}}\le \frac{x+y+z}{3^{1\over 3}}$$ which is obviously wrong.

Comment: Try taking 3 dimensional vectors, and use Schwarz inequality. In general, take n dimensional vectors

Comment: @BuluBestTapu  Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details [HERE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what to do to obtain a geometric proof (of course many proofs exist e.g. using convexity of the exponential function), but to relate the quantities via linear algebra I suggest
$$
\det\pmatrix{x & y & z\\
y&  z& x\\
z &  x & y} =3xyz-(x^3+y^3+z^3).$$

Answer (score 2):

By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality with

- $u=\left(\sqrt[3] {xy^\frac12},\sqrt[3] { yz^\frac12}, \sqrt[3] {zx^\frac12}\right)$
- $v=\left(\sqrt[3] {y^\frac12z},\sqrt[3] {xz^\frac12}, \sqrt[3] {x^\frac12y}\right)$

we obtain

$$uv\le |u||v| \iff 3\sqrt[3]{xyz}\le\sqrt{\left(\sqrt[3] {x^2y}+\sqrt[3] {y^2z}+\sqrt[3] {z^2x}\right)\left( \sqrt[3]{yz^2}+\sqrt[3]{x^2z}+\sqrt[3]{xy^2}\right)}\le \sqrt{\left(\sqrt[3] {x^3}+\sqrt[3] {y^3}+\sqrt[3] {z^3}\right)\left( \sqrt[3]{z^3}+\sqrt[3]{x^3}+\sqrt[3]{y^3}\right)}=x+y+z$$

Comment: Where is the last $\leq$ from? Is it from the [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality)?

Comment: @awllower yes exactly!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\text{AM-GM}_n$ stands for the statement of the arithmetic-geometric inequality in $n$ variables. A classical, elementary approach (due to Cauchy, *Cours d'Analyse*) is to show

$$ \text{AM-GM}_2 \vdash \text{AM-GM}_4 \vdash\text{AM-GM}_3.$$
Should I provide further details, or you prefer to figure them out by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

**An Identity which Proves the Inequality**
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac12\left((x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2\right)(x+y+z)\\
&+3x(y-z)^2+3y(z-x)^2+3z(x-y)^2\\[4pt]
&=(x+y+z)^3-27xyz
\end{align}
$$
and the inequality follows.

---

**Motivation Behind the Identity**

Knowing that the extreme points of $(x+y+z)^3-27xyz$ are when $x=y=z$, we should look at
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac12\left((x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2\right)\\
&=x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx\\[4pt]
&=(x+y+z)^2-3(xy+yz+zx)
\end{align}
$$
Multiply by $x+y+z$
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac12\left((x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2\right)(x+y+z)\\
&=(x+y+z)^3-3(xy+yz+zx)(x+y+z)\\[4pt]
&=(x+y+z)^3-9xyz-3xy^2-3xz^2-3yz^2-3yx^2-3zx^2-2zy^2\\[4pt]
&=(x+y+z)^3-27xyz-3x(y-z)^2-3y(z-x)^2-3z(x-y)^2
\end{align}
$$
and the identity follows.